# PHP access foreach to iterate json data multiple object

Tags: php, json

I'm facing an error when trying to post JSON data into PHP. I am new at this.
any helps makes good for us

the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "sections": [
            {
                "section_id": "62",
                "section_name": "English Language",
                
            }  
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "questions": [
            {
                "section_id": "62",
                "questionid": "1231",
                 
            },
            {
                "section_id": "62",
                "questionid": "1232",
                "time_spent": "0",
                "status": "unseen",
                "testsession_id": "whqgo41nsyurpi2"
            },
            {
                "section_id": "62",
                "questionid": "1233",
               
            } 
             
        ]
    } 
]
```

below is the code I wrote. Please correct the PHP code to access those JSON values.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
foreach ($data['sections'] as $value){
    echo $value[section_id];
}
foreach ($data['questions'] as $value){
    echo $value[section_id];
}
```

Comment: I would recommend fixing the code that generates the JSON . It's currently in a sub optimal format. since you have "sections" and "questions" properties inside different objects wrapped in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the array aspect of the JSON. The JSON is made up of an array firstly, which contains 2 objects, which have parameters of `sections` in the first, and `questions` in the second.

`sections` and `questions` are both arrays, which can be iterated over using foreach, which returns each of the elements as an object.

Your code after decoding the JSON should be like this.

```
foreach ($data[0]['sections'] as $value){
  echo $value['section_id'];
}
foreach ($data[1]['questions'] as $value){
  echo $value['section_id'];
}
```

Comment: the json data is decoded into an array, shouldn't it be accessed with ``$data[0]['sections']`` instead of ``$data[0]->sections``?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I will update the answer.